# Fragment showing nothing when starting my app for first time

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an app with bottom navigation fragment activity
I have placed text views and buttons on my home fragment.
further these fragments are placed in a frame layout.
when I launch my app my home fragment shows nothing just blank screen it loads everything when I
switch between fragments.

I want to fix this, so that when I launch my app everything that is on my home fragment shows up.

Answer (score 0):

because you didn't specify the first fragment to show,

in the onCreate you have to do this :

first checked the bottomNavigation item, that you want to start with :

```
 bottomNavigation.getMenu().findItem(R.id.item).setChecked(true);
```

then put the first fragment in frame layout